# Method does not exist - {List}.get(Decimal)

Tags: list, method, decimal

I get errors for the last line.

> Method does not exist - {List}.get(Decimal)

`opp.Most_Expensive_Competitor_Price__c = oppCompetitorPrices.get(highestPrice);`

I am trying to populate the Most_Expensive_Competitor_Price__c with the Highest Price

```
trigger MostExpensiveCompetitor on Opportunity (before insert, before update) {

    for (Opportunity opp: Trigger.new) {

        // create a list to add the competitor prices

        List <Decimal> oppCompetitorPrices = new List <Decimal> ();  

        oppCompetitorPrices.add(opp.Competitor_1_Price__c); 
        oppCompetitorPrices.add(opp.Competitor_2_Price__c); 
        oppCompetitorPrices.add(opp.Competitor_3_Price__c); 

        // create a list to add the competitors in the same order

        List <String> competitors = new List <String> (); 

        competitors.add(opp.Competitor_1__c); 
        competitors.add(opp.Competitor_2__c); 
        competitors.add(opp.Competitor_3__c); 

        Decimal highestPrice; 
        Integer highestPricePosition; 

        for (Integer i=0; i<oppCompetitorPrices.size(); i++) {

            Decimal currentHighestPrice = oppCompetitorPrices.get(i); 

            if (highestPrice ==null || currentHighestPrice > highestPrice) {

                highestPrice = currentHighestPrice; 
                highestPricePosition = i; 

            }




        }

            opp.The_Most_Expensive_Competitor__c = competitors.get(highestPricePosition); 
            opp.Most_Expensive_Competitor_Price__c = oppCompetitorPrices.get(highestPrice); 


    }



}
```

Comment: List does not support **Decimal** in index as you are fetching the element by  providing the decimal value. First convert it to integer and then try to get the element.

Comment: Best would be to use list sorting method in wrapper class

Answer (score 0):

The Get method of List is used to retrieve the element at that index. In your logic, you are using `oppCompetitorPrices.get(highestPrice);` There are 2 issues here

- {List}.get accepts integer parameter while you are passing it a decimal. Convert it to a integer before using get.
- Even after you convert it, I am not sure what you are doing by passing the highestPrice parameter. HighestPrice in your logic is the highest price rather than the index of highest price.

As Rahul Sharma has pointed out, it would be better to use the {List}.sort() method to sort the data. It will sort in ascending order and the last element will have the highest price. You can get that by `{List}.get({list}.size() - 1);`

Comment: Hi. I tried using the List.get as suggested and still not working. I'll keep trying.